# Jetpack Navigation: On button click show textview text on another screen's textview

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

On screen 2 I have a button which when clicked shows the text ("MON") in the textview. I also want that day that has been selected by the user to be shown on another screen (screen 4) so not the next screen in the navigation menu but the one after. So if the user selects days Monday, Wednesday and Friday by clicking the buttons on screen 2, I want the days to appear on that screen but then also to appear on screen 4. I have attempted the code and can get the text to appear on screen 2 but not on screen 4. How would I solve this?

```
private fun onButtonClicked() {
        when {
            select_day_mon_img_btn.setOnClickListener {
                select_day_mon_word_txt.text = resources.getString(R.string.mon)
                home_day_word_txt.text = getString(R.string.mon)
                home_day_word_txt.setOnClickListener {
                    view?.findNavController()?.navigate(
                        R.id.action_selectDaysFragment_to_homeFragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun select(day: String) {
        selected.value = day
    }
}
```

On 2nd screen pass selected day into viewmodel

```
class Screen2 : Fragment() {


    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        home_day_word_txt.setOnClickListener {
            model.select(getString(R.string.mon))
            view?.findNavController()?.navigate(
                    R.id.action_selectDaysFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

On 4th screen

```
class Screen4 : Fragment() {

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        model.selected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String> { day ->
                // Update the UI
                textView.text = day
        })
    }
}
```